# What is the protocol for making modifications to someone else's proof to prove something slightly stronger?

Tags: alternative-proof, soft-question

I have a need to modify Erdős' proof of the Sylvester-Schur Theorem to prove something stronger.  See my working document at http://math.rudytoody.us/ or http://math.rudytoody.us/OppermannTheorem.pdf

If I have to modify most of the proof, I will use the entire proof (with proper attribution, of course.)  However, I don't believe I will need to do that.  So, how much should I show of the original?  Could I do a line-by-line comparison of the changes?  If I only change a few variables, could I do something along the lines of, "By changing variables a, b, c and relaxing condition x, it's easy to see that Erdős' proof arrives at the same conclusion without breaking the original."

Some suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Short answer: "It depends on who your audience is, and what they might expect of you"

Comment: I don't see why you would make a line-by-line comparison unless you were writing a textbook on proofs. 

Comment: @Yemon Choi--let's say it's this audience.

Comment: Most people in *this audience* to not have the Erdös paper handy, so probably your including a complete proof would be best.

Comment: Heck, I didn't even know what the Sylvester-Schur theorem (see http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~pppollac/sschur.pdf) was. My guess is that most people won't know the theorem. So I'd agree with Gerald Edgar: if it's *this audience*, you should provide a complete statement and proof. You can then comment on how the proof compares to that of Erd&ouml;s if you like, or say that it is patterned after that of Erd&ouml;s, or whatever. BTW: I didn't feel like copying and entering your link into my browser -- laziness. Why don't you provide a direct link? 

Comment: Erring on the side of caution is best here: you can always write out the whole proof; if an editor or referee feels it's unnecessary, they will probably point it out. 

Comment: I suggest you write your own proof completely, then mention that your proof is a modification of the proof of Erdös, then cite his paper.

Comment: No one has said (and I haven't checked to see) how long the proof is. If it's 100 pages, it's probably not a good idea to include the whole of the proof. 

Comment: @Gerry Myerson--It's nine pages, which is why I thought it might become an exhibit withing my proof.

Comment: Rudy, I had no end of trouble with a co-author who gave me drafts with Tex spit out from Maple. No matter how informal, these days any method of publication (such as the arXiv) will expect an initial submission as, say, a pdf, but in the event of acceptance, say, will require an understandable .tex file. Even if you are just distributing copies to friends, you need a finished, and fairly polished, article in order to get people to read it.

Comment: @Will Jagy--This is my first try at using Mathematica to produce html for my web page.  I have had difficulty doing that from LaTeX.  The purpose of the web page is to get this problem before the world.  If someone else proves it before I do, great!  I just need it to be true to prove a stronger version of Brocard's Conjecture so I can prove what I started 4 years ago.  In fact, it wasn't until a few months ago that I found that I was trying to prove Oppermann's Conjecture.  There was nothing in the literature like it.  I was about to call it the Toody Theorem!

Comment: Alright, it seems your main concern at the moment is getting a good reading copy on your website. What my friend did for me was to set up some pages that allowed me to post (primarily) pdfs in such a way that a viewer can click on them and either read on the computer screen or download and print out. So I encourage you to get some html help and do that, see my sites http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/forms.html  and   http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/   
It is not that common to have nine pages all in html. Well, write to me if you like...

Comment: Erdős, not Erdös.

Comment: @TonyK--Fixed, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm following Todd Trimble's suggestion and writing my comment as an answer:

I suggest you write your own proof completely, then mention that your proof is a modification of the proof of Erdős, then cite his paper.